# fancybox: change height and width property after

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Yes i have a simple fancybox with specified height and width.

When you click a link inside this fancybox it runs a ajax request. On this request´s success, i wish the fancybox to change height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div for your ajax, and another to contain it. Have the containing div be fixed height and `overflow: hidden`. When the ajax loads run `.height()` with jQuery on the inner div, then assign a variable and have the container `.animate()` to fit.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but still valid:

```
$.fancybox.update()

// Auto-sizes fancyBox height to match height of content
```

or

```
$.fancybox.toggle()

// If content is resized to fit inside viewport than it will be expanded to full size (and vice verse)
```